# Java Sockets - Sending different types of information from server to client and vica versa only when needed

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

So the way I have done this Multi-Client Server and client connection, is to have the server create a new Thread for each client, and then use a while loop to constantly recieve, output, store, and then send the data from each of the clients to the specific client for this Thread by using ArrayList:

```
while (!finished) {
        numberofclients = Server.clients.size();
        inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        v3f = (Vector3f) inStream.readObject();//recieve object from client

        clientinfo.setText("[" + clientindex + "] " + clientname + ": " //jlabel to show this clients position in server class
                    + (int) v3f.x + "," + (int) v3f.y + "," + (int) v3f.z);
        FontToFit(clientinfo);

        Server.clientpos.set(clientindex-1, v3f);//the arraylist of client positions

        outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outStream.writeObject(Server.clientpos);//send the clients positions

}
```

It works great for my game, each player connects, and you can see where each one is (although its not terribly fast), but I cannot hope to advance with this game if I continue to use sockets this way. I also plan to make a chat in the game, but if I used that right now, it would conflict with the data being sent for their positions. I wish I knew how to only send information when needed, and the client would only try to receive it when needed.

In the server class some method like:

```
public void SendPositionsToAll(){
    for(ClientThread ct : clients){//for each client
    ct.SendPos(ct.x, ct.y, ct.z);// run method in ClientThread
    }
}
```

And then in ClientThread:

```
public void SendPos(double x, double y, double z){
outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
outStream.writeObject(new Vector3f(x,y,z));
}
```

With something similar for the chat. I have no clue if it is possible (guessing it is) but any help would be awesome.

Comment: This is a very large question which there are entire books covering. The first thing you may want to define : when is communication "needed"? *or, is that the question you are really trying to ask?*

Comment: First things first: what you need to do is develop a flexible protocol (or adopt an existing one).

Answer (score 1):

dedicate a thread to receiving messages and queueing them.
dedicate a thread to sending objects that have been queued for it.

you could continue to use serialization, but as you say it's not terribly effecient.

..or you could implement a communication protocol that packs just the essential information.
If you do, I highly recommend making it human readable.  Doing so will make your debugging
life a whole lot easier.